# Pass user id in a mail form for registered user

Tags: php, authentication

I would like to pass the user id (which is the email, in this case) in an email form. Here the PHP for registered users only:

```
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
'zubrag' => 'root',
'admin' => 'adminpass',
'phuket@iceagethai.com' => 'phuket'
);
```

Here what I use in the form:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php global $id; ?>">
```

How should I write the form field? I googled around but I am confused...

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what your question is.

Comment: Are you sure your login_information array is correct? the array should have fixed indices before you can use that. If not, you will have to use numerical indices.

Comment: Using an unkown array key as your user id sounds like a bad idea, there is no easy / foul-proof way to retrieve that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['LOGIN']; ?>">
```

That works for me

Answer (score 2):

what is the importance of inserting the user id on input field?
if you want to reuse the user id after the user is login to the system, assign the user id to on session variable and get user id from session variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The user will fill an order form as is a sale agent and the main office should see from who the order came from without let the user write his/her username again after log in